# Generics in Typescript - interface Method vs Property

Tags: typescript

Why does Typescript's Syntax support this (interface method):

```
interface myInterface{

    myObject<T extends myValidatedObject>(obj: Object) : T;
}
```

But not this (property) :

```
interface myInterface{

    myObject<T extends myValidatedObject>: (obj: Object) => T;
}
```

Comment: No, I am talking about Generics here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because a property cannot be generic. A property can represent a generic function, but the generic parameters need to be on the function type not on the property:

```
interface myInterface {
    myObject: <T extends myValidatedObject>(obj: Object) => T;
}
```